# Split string in array of determined size without split word

Tags: javascript

I need to create function that be able to splite a larger string into array of smaller string but whiteout split word.
In my case I have a large text message with more than 5000 character and I need to split into string of 2048 character.

.

So to do that I have create this function (for the example I split into 512 characther):

```js
  var split = function(input, maxCharacter) {
    var returnString = "";
    var returnArray = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      returnString += input[i];
      if (returnString.length >= maxCharacter) {
        var sav = returnString.length - 1;
        var j = returnString.length - 1;
        while (returnString[j] !== " " && j > maxCharacter * 0.9) {
          returnString = returnString.slice(0, returnString.length - 1);
          j = j - 1;
        }
        returnArray.push(returnString);
        returnString = "";
        i = i - (sav - j);
      }
    }
    return returnArray;
  };

  console.log(
    split(
      `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor rhoncus ex non tristique. Cras in consectetur dui, tincidunt luctus dui. Duis suscipit volutpat ex nec lacinia. Nullam vitae nibh orci. Fusce laoreet fermentum leo eu tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed id quam diam. Quisque tempus orci quis nibh pretium luctus. Aenean fermentum, risus at pretium tristique, urna ipsum luctus felis, molestie luctus purus mi vitae ligula. Etiam elementum viverra orci ut maximus. Pellentesque interdum vel leo sed tristique.Integer est ligula, sodales a viverra eget, molestie eget ex. Vivamus hendrerit fermentum magna ac suscipit. Sed vitae sem leo. In eget eleifend sapien. Nunc congue, orci non accumsan placerat, sapien nulla tristique ante, eget dignissim quam diam non ipsum. Aenean lacinia nec erat consequat bibendum. Proin aliquam lobortis sem, ultricies efficitur mi fringilla et. Duis eu venenatis sapien. Nulla iaculis pharetra rhoncus. Suspendisse convallis convallis purus quis imperdiet.`,
      512
    )
  );
```

But with this function I get the first String or the two first string.
And sometime I just have infinity loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fast: https://jsben.ch/Tve2y

```js
    const string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    function split(str,length) {
      let i,j,result = []
      // for each character in the string
      for (i=0,j=str.length; i<j; i+=length) {
          // this variable is to get the first space before the chunk length
          let c = 0
          // while you don't encounter a space, you go backwards
          while (i+length<str.length && !(/\s/.test(str[i+length-c]))) { c++ }
          // you save the chunk
          result.push(str.slice(i,i+length-c))
          i -= c - 1
      }
      return result
    }

    console.log(split(string, 20))
```

This one is faster

```js
const string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

function split(str,length) {
  let i=0,j,result = []
  do {
    j = str.slice(i,i+length).lastIndexOf(" ")+1
    result.push(str.slice(i,i+j-1))
  } while ((i + length < str.length) && (i += j))
  return result.concat(str.slice(i+j))
}

console.log(split(string, 20))
```

Comment: I have a big message to send but the size of discord message was limited to 2048 character. That why I need to split the big message. But because it's a message I don't want to split word in two message. So if i encount word I want to place this word in the next cell.

Comment: OK I understood your problem and here is a faster algorithm (Karan answer was good but you lose performance)

Comment: And my code takes into account the spaces at the beginning of each chunk ;)

Comment: I have try your code it's perfect I have test the time. And with your code the processing this done in 115ms and the oder solution is end with 280ms. So it's way more better thanks !

Comment: I think I can improve my code, give me a few minutes... :)

Answer (score 2):

Not extremely fast but is quite flexible.

```js
var split = (stringValue, splitChar) => {
  const splitBy = splitChar ? splitChar : ' ';

  const occuranceMatch = (stringValue.match(new RegExp(splitBy, 'g')) || []);
  if (!occuranceMatch) {
    return stringValue;
  }

  const totalSplitByOccurances = occuranceMatch.length;
  if (totalSplitByOccurances === 0) {
    return stringValue;
  }

  const start = 0;
  let splitIndex = stringValue.indexOf(splitBy);
  let tempStringValue = stringValue.slice();
  const strings = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < totalSplitByOccurances; ++i) {
    const value = tempStringValue.substring(start, splitIndex);
    strings.push(value.trim());

    tempStringValue = tempStringValue.substring(splitIndex + 1, tempStringValue.length).trim();
    splitIndex = tempStringValue.indexOf(splitBy);
  }

  return strings;
}


const string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

console.log(split(string, ','));

// or 

console.log(split(string));
```

Comment: Actually your code is faster than you think, nice done.

Comment: Oh it's cool because you can chose the split character ^^. And it's pretty fast :). But the code of djcaesar9114 was mutch faster with is code the processing is done in 115ms but with your code it's done in 217ms.

Comment: But you have to take into account the length of each chunk :)

Comment: @djcaesar9114 Yep while implementing the function I forgot to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `lastIndexOfSpace` with `var lastIndexOfSpace = input.lastIndexOf(' ', maxCharacter);`.

Split your string with that index. Add first part into array and process same function for next portion of the string.

I've added explanation into the code so it would be easy to understand the logic.

```js
var split = function(input, maxCharacter, splitValue=' ') {
  // if input length is less than or equal to max allowed length then return it wrapping in array.
  if (input.length <= maxCharacter) {
    return [input];
  }
  // get index of space before max allowed length, from where string needs to be split.
  var lastIndexOfSpace = input.lastIndexOf(splitValue, maxCharacter);
  // push first portion of string as initial index
  // process second portion of string again with split.
  // use spread operator ... to merge strings into single array.
  return [input.slice(0, lastIndexOfSpace), ...split(input.slice(lastIndexOfSpace+splitValue.length), maxCharacter)];
}


console.log(
  split(
    `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce auctor rhoncus ex non tristique. Cras in consectetur dui, tincidunt luctus dui. Duis suscipit volutpat ex nec lacinia. Nullam vitae nibh orci. Fusce laoreet fermentum leo eu tincidunt. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed id quam diam. Quisque tempus orci quis nibh pretium luctus. Aenean fermentum, risus at pretium tristique, urna ipsum luctus felis, molestie luctus purus mi vitae ligula. Etiam elementum viverra orci ut maximus. Pellentesque interdum vel leo sed tristique.Integer est ligula, sodales a viverra eget, molestie eget ex. Vivamus hendrerit fermentum magna ac suscipit. Sed vitae sem leo. In eget eleifend sapien. Nunc congue, orci non accumsan placerat, sapien nulla tristique ante, eget dignissim quam diam non ipsum. Aenean lacinia nec erat consequat bibendum. Proin aliquam lobortis sem, ultricies efficitur mi fringilla et. Duis eu venenatis sapien. Nulla iaculis pharetra rhoncus. Suspendisse convallis convallis purus quis imperdiet.`,
    20
  ));
```

Comment: You don't take into account the spaces at the beginning of each chunk ;)

Comment: Better, but there is still room for performance improvement, my code is faster: https://jsben.ch/lYzYp ;)